# React 18+ navigation

Tags: navigation

I am navigating back in my react app. But, the moment move back in my browser the url changes but the data is not changing and the previous data is not showing.

I have build a searchBar component for searching for movies. Whenever I search for more than twice, the data for the first or previous searching is not showing. Eventhough the URL changes back to preivous search. but the page is not changing to show movies for previous searchText. I really appreciate if someone would help me here. Thanks